# Which team has scored the most goals during the group stage of a single UEFA Champions League?

Tags: football, trivia, records, champions-league

PSG just finished first of Group B in the UEFA Champions League Group stage.

PSG scored 25 times during the six games, finishing with an average goalscoring rate of 4.1666 per match.

Is this the greatest number of goals scored by a single team during the group stage? If it is not, which team has scored more goals?

Comment: I will add that the following is mentioned in the Wikipedia article [European Cup and UEFA Champions League records and statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Cup_and_UEFA_Champions_League_records_and_statistics#Specific_group_stage_records) ([current revision](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=European_Cup_and_UEFA_Champions_League_records_and_statistics&oldid=834461116#Specific_group_stage_records)): Most goals scored in a group stage: 25 - Paris Saint-Germain (2017–18). (No reference is given there.)

Answer (score 5):

[According to UEFA themselves, at December 6, 2017](http://www.uefa.com/uefachampionsleague/news/newsid=2499027.html#/) this is indeed the greatest number of goals scored in a campaign, and is therefore the greatest number of goals scored in the group stage, by a single club.