# Which team has scored the most goals during a single whole UEFA Champions League season?

Tags: football, trivia, records, champions-league

Which team has scored the most goals during a single whole UEFA Champions League season, including their games in the group stage and any knockout matches they played?

Comment: Similar: [Which team has scored the most goals during the group stage of a single UEFA Champions League?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/17430/which-team-has-scored-the-most-goals-during-the-group-stage-of-a-single-uefa-cha)

Answer (score 4):

From UEFA CHAMPIONS LEAGUE STATISTICS HANDBOOK 2017/18 [Facts and Figures (pg. no. 11)](http://www.uefa.com/MultimediaFiles/Download/EuroExperience/competitions/Publications/02/28/56/88/2285688_DOWNLOAD.pdf)

> Most goals scored in a season:
>
> 45 from 16 games (av. 2.81) FC Barcelona 1999/00
>
> 41 from 13 games (av. 3.15) Real Madrid CF 2013/14
>
> 36 from 13 games (av. 2.77) Real Madrid CF 2016/17
>
> 35 from 12 games (av. 2.92) FC Barcelona 2011/12
>
> 35 from 12 games (av. 2.92) Real Madrid CF 2011/12
>
> 35 from 16 games (av. 2.19) Real Madrid CF 2000/01
>
> 35 from 17 games (av. 2.06) Real Madrid CF 1999/00
>
> 35 from 17 games (av. 2.06) Real Madrid CF 2001/02

[Visit this link](https://www.uefa.com/uefachampionsleague/season=2018/statistics/round=2000881/clubs/kind=goals/index.html#order=1desc) for current season stats.